# A Better way to Improve the performance of a series of REST API calls

Tags: rest, moshi

A REST client consumes a series of API calls, 6 to be exact. They take a notable time to complete those series of calls even though both applications are in the same machine. The code is something like the following:

```
    // 1.
    CreateUserOption createUserOption = new CreateUserOption(username, jobCandidatePassword, email, fullName);
    Optional<User> userOptional = createUserAccount(createUserOption, tokenValue);
    if (userOptional.isEmpty()) return false;

    // 2. 
    GenerateRepoOption generateRepoOption = new GenerateRepoOption(templateName.replace("template", "") + username, templateOwner);
    Optional<Repository> repositoryOptional = this.generateRepo(generateRepoOption, templateOwner, templateName, tokenValue);
    if (repositoryOptional.isEmpty()) return false;

    // 3. 
    TransferRepoOption transferRepoOption = new TransferRepoOption(username);
    Optional<Repository> transferRepositoryOptional = transferRepo(
        transferRepoOption,
        repositoryOptional.get().getOwner().getLogin(),
        repositoryOptional.get().getName(),
        tokenValue
    );
    if (transferRepositoryOptional.isEmpty()) return false;

    // 4.
    List<Organization> organizations = this.getOrganizationsOfCurrentUser(tokenValue);
    if (!organizations.isEmpty()) {
        // 5.
        Organization organization = organizations.get(0);
        Optional<Team> teamOptional =
            this.createTeamInOrganization(new CreateTeamOption("t-" + username), organization.getUsername(), tokenValue);
        if (!teamOptional.isEmpty()) {
            // 6.
            this.addTeamMember(teamOptional.get().getId(), username, tokenValue);
        }
    }
    return true;
```

and those functions are consuming a REST API. For example,

```
  private Optional<User> createUserAccount(CreateUserOption account, String tokenValue) {
    log.debug(":::: createUserAccount : {}", account.toString());

    String postBody = createUserOptionJsonAdapter.toJson(account);
    okhttp3.RequestBody body = okhttp3.RequestBody.create(postBody, okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/json"));
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(apiBaseurl + "/admin/users")
        .header("User-Agent", "OkHttp Headers.java")
        .addHeader("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString())
        .addHeader("Authorization", "token " + tokenValue)
        .post(body)
        .build();

    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            log.error(response.code() + " - " + response.message());
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        User user = giteaUserJsonAdapter.fromJson(response.body().string());
        return Optional.of(user);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        log.error(ioe.getMessage());
        return Optional.empty();
    }
  }
```

Those 6 calls can be divided into two groups and 3 calls in each group, the next call needs the returned data from the previous one. Firing another thread for one group of API calls is one way to improve the performance.

Any better approaches on the client?

The client app is built with Java and Moshi HTTP client library.

Comment: Create a new API (nr 7) which combines the functionality of 1 through 6 ? This would eliminate 5x network time which is probably the "notable time" you are referring to.

Comment: We can't change anything in the REST server.

Comment: You don't have many options here. One idea is to run some of those API calls in parallel, if possible. If the execution of these 6 API calls is triggered by another API call, you could make it "asynchronous" by returning the 202 [HTTP status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202). Anyway, if you want to be sure that the bottleneck is in the API calls themselves, check how we find and fix the bottleneck in our APIs at [apaleo](https://apaleo.com/) by reading [this blog post](https://medium.com/apaleo-engineering/how-apaleo-improves-api-performance-9c10695740c1).